# Ruby Split array in sub arrays that contain only different values

Tags: arrays, ruby, algorithm

I have an array of the following form:

```
[20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21]
```

I'm trying to find a way to split the array in sub arrays that contain only different values.
For example:

```
[[20,21], [20,21], [21], [21]]
```

This example only contains two different values but irl the main array could contain multiple different values.

Another example would be [20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22] => [[20,21,22], [20,21], [21], [21]]

It's important that if the main array has for example 6 elements, the resultant sub arrays in total would equal that quantity.

I've been playing **combination, permutation and group_by** but haven't been able to accomplish this.

Comment: How about `[20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21].map { |n| [n] }`? I doubt that this is what you want, but it is a way of suggesting that your criteria are incomplete.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".
Did you research this? Where? If it didn't help tell us why. What did you try? If you didn't try, why not? If you did, what did you do? We'd like to see your minimal attempt to solve it.

Comment: Could you show us what have you done so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to have the minimum number of subarrays.

```
arr = [20, 20, 21, 21, 21, 21, 22, 23, 22]
```

```
h = arr.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |n,h| h[n] += 1 }
  #=> {20=>2, 21=>4, 22=>2, 23=>1} 
a = Array.new(h.values.max) { Array.new { [] } }
  #=> [[], [], [], []] 
h.each { |n,freq| freq.times { |i| a[i] << n } }
a #=> [[20, 21, 22, 23], [20, 21, 22], [21], [21]]
```

```
h.values.max
  #=> 4
```

tells us we need at least 4 subarrays (for `21`). `4` is clearly sufficient as we simply allocate each group of equal elements to different subarrays.

See the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a default value and [Array::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Array.html#method-c-new).

If `h = Hash.new(0)`, then if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` returns the default value, here zero. When `h[k] += 1` is executed Ruby's first step is to convert that expression to:

```
h[k] = h[k] + 1
```

If `h` does not have a key `k` the expression `h[k]` on the right of the equality returns zero.

A variant (after computing `h`) is the following:

```
h.each_with_object([]) do |(n,freq),a|
  freq.times { |i| i >= a.size ? a << [n] : a[i] << n }
end
  #=> [[20, 21, 22, 23], [20, 21, 22], [21], [21]]
```

Comment: thanks you, worked wonders!

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: I've just re-read your example and it doesn't appear your wanting what I've suggested below.

Sounds like you're wanting a `Enumerable#chunk_while` that also gives you the current chunk. Assuming you're using a [modern version of Ruby (>= 1.9)](https://www.igvita.com/2009/02/04/ruby-19-internals-ordered-hash/) I believe you can rely on the keys below being ordered:

```
def chunk_while_uniq(enum)
  return [] if enum.empty?

  groups = enum.each_with_object([{}]) do |e, acc|
    if acc.last.has_key? e
      acc.push({ e => true })
    else
      acc.last[e] = true
    end
  end

  groups.map(&:keys)
end

p chunk_while_uniq([20, 21, 21, 20, 20, 21, 21, 21])
p chunk_while_uniq([:test, :test, :new, :diff, :test, :test])
```

The above will work with anything that can be compared, not just numbers.

https://repl.it/repls/FittingAlphanumericSubversion